# Some basic ambiguities on ASP.NET WebSite publishing

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I managed to create a WebForms Project which I now published via Ftp-option my host provides. The first problem I encountered was that I had all my redirect calls pointing to a hard coded localhost-URL:

```
Response.Redirect("http://localhost:XYZAV/SearchResults.aspx);
```

My hosts server certainly can not redirect to that url. So I had to change all my redirect calls to url's the server knew. But this seems to be not the best option to deal with this problem. I mean I would have to chenge them every time I publish, plus for developement I would also have to change them back again.

I never had to use this option but I guess this is what the "Debug" and the "Release" options are there for, am I right? But I encounter two problems:

1. I simply do not have the "Release" option in "Visual Studio 2013" for this project.
2. Even if I had, what would be best practice to handle this issue?

I hope I made myself clear if not I will provide as much more information as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First time ever seen this kind of line - '`Response.Redirect("http://localhost:XYZAV/SearchResults.aspx);`'?? OR it should `Response.Redirect("SearchResults.aspx);`?

Comment: @Prog Serverside redirect call: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It should - `Response.Redirect("SearchResults.aspx);`

Comment: @Prog I tried that and of course you are right! This actually does solve my issue. So is the Release-context never used in ASP.NEt at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use This**

It should -

`Response.Redirect("SearchResults.aspx);`

Comment: That was some easy reputation wasn't it? :D